# Jackson dynamic property name

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I am looking for a smart solution how to read a JSON response form a HTTP response, that could contain dynamic property name(s).

Let's consider a data model that I am mapping JSON into (Kotlin code):

```
data class Response(
    @JsonProperty("id") val id: String,
    @JsonProperty("xyz_Value") val value: String
)
```

Now, the tricky part here is that the `xyz_` prefix for value is dynamic (treat it a environmental variable, so ie. it can be `dev_Value` or `prod_Value`)

Is there an existing elegant solution I can go with?

Comment: So you have many classes having similar behavior and I guess that also  "xyz_Value" can be determined in different heuristics? You could give an example of one or two more classes for which this sophisticated solution should also apply without multiple custom deserializers. Maybe you just want to keep one data class Response and no others?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom deserializer `JsonDeserializer<Response>` and map the `value` field according to your environment

Comment: Correct, but this is not an ideal solution for me, as I have plenty of different classes with similar behavior. Therefore I don't want to end up with multiple custom deserializers

Comment: @dk007 custom behaviour == custom deserializer